# Padding doesn't work properly in EditText Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, padding

Hello I have a question,
In Android Studio's prewiew when I use "padding" and "gravity" those look fine, Galaxy s4, the EditText doesn't show the text in the same position. This show it a little bit above.

thats my xml

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/eta"
    android:hint="a"
    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ecuacion1"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textColorHint="#ff757575" />
```

thanks.

Comment: Its because of you have given hard coded padding android:paddingBottom="6dp". Remove padding bottom

Comment: Hello, I added that line because in the phone the cursor is shown a little above